# Which JDK required for Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, java

Nice day to all and little question:

JDK 6 or JDK 7 require for latest Android SDK? Which is more prefer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by Android requirements :

- Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) or greater Note: Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) is no
  longer supported with the latest version of ADT.
- Eclipse JDT plugin(included in most Eclipse IDE packages)
- JDK 6 (JRE    alone is not sufficient)
- Android Development Tools plugin    (recommended)
- Not compatible with Gnu Compiler for Java (gcj)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Downvotes, without any explanation is not helping, even if the question is bad, doesn't mean the answers are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Get JDK 7 if you are unsure. It works and and is more recent.